# C# rendering graph

Tags: c#

i have to render a graph in my web page.i have desigened a class( in C#) file which contain a event for rendering a graph(pie chart).In that event i pass some value i.e 
legends which is a string[] and value which is double[] to draw the graph.
But i want that instead of inserting the value directly into the event, pass that value with some function like

```
public void insertvalue(string[] legends,double[] values)
{

}
```

how could i do that plese help me????????
And i am using Zedgraphweb control to render the graph.

Comment: What specifically is your question? How to produce a bitmap containing the chart, or how to pass values around?

Comment: i am asking about how to pass value in that event

Comment: i am using zedgraphweb control

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Key-Value pair collection such as a dictionary and use it to construct the pie chart, something like `<legend, value>`. 
You can also create a custom object that has two fields, Legend and Value and use it to build a collection such as an arraylist or a simple array. You can find information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx?msg=2695266) regarding the ZedGraph Control.